# Push notification for Android applications

Tags: android

Do we have any equivalent service of Push Notification (in iPhone) for Android applications?

Comment: Google released a push notification API with 2.2 but I can't for the life of me find a thing about it on the sdk site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, here is a good tutorial with all code you need:

http://blog.boxedice.com/2010/10/07/android-push-notifications-tutorial/

http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android/

Answer (score 9):

The way to go is using C2dM the official google push api

http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html

instead of building it yourself.

To support older phones and/or if you don't really need real time notification, you can use polling. Check out the BuzzBox SDK as the simplest way of adding a scheduler and notifications to your apps. http://hub.buzzbox.com

Answer (score 5):

use [this link](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html) for learn and source code for push notification in android and build on android 1.6 you can use MQTT library. And for testing push notification in emulator refer [this link.](http://bhutiyagirish.wordpress.com/2011/07/29/testing-push-notification-android-market-in-emulator/)

Answer (score 1):

[Android Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM) - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html)