# In android how to get push notifications to the mobile from the server?

Tags: android

I'm entering the details in the database (server) about the schedule for the travel according to the date and time of travel. Before Half an hour of travel time the server has to send the notification to the traveller.To do so is it required of any middle ware like MQTT protocol from IBM?

if anyone have got result in implementing this or have any idea about it then kindly share it so that i can get the idea and try to implement it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576211/push-notification-for-android-applications

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if your target audience can reasonably be assumed to be all signed into a Google account on the mobile device (an account is required to use the Android market after all), then use the Google's push notifications ([C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html)).

Otherwise, you will need to roll your own push notifications. The link in Cephron's comment should help you further along that path.

Comment: thank you codinguser but i'm not able to find cephron's comment can please help me.

Comment: This is the link in the comment on your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576211/push-notification-for-android-applications

Comment: thankx codinguser,                                                        I got the notification by using the tokudu code its working fine but i'm in need to get from the server built by me to the app. but in this case we have to type the msg to be pushed in its own site  then only we ll get the notification. And i didn't get the registration key for the C2DM even after the confirmation msg from the google. If u have any idea how to get notification from the server built by us then please share the information with me. thank you for ur support codinguser.

Comment: Do you mean the confirmation message allowing you to use C2DM? That only allows the email address you registered with to use the service. I think the your Android app has to register with Google using ClientLogin and then you will get a registration id from Google. Your application then needs to send that id to your server, which will then use it to contact Google's servers. Without the registration_id, Google will not send your notification. See this Google page for the role of your server: http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html#server